Binomial distribution as Taylor expansion
I just noticed as a surprise for myself that Binomial probability can be cast into a Taylor expansion of a ("dah") binomial as:
$(q+p)^n = q^n + nq^{n-1}p + ... + C^n_p q^{n-r}p^r + .. + p^n + O(n+1)$
for small $p$ or $q$ depending on a problem. Then, Binomial distribution is a Taylor expansion of a binomial $(q+p)^n$ where $n$ (# of trials) is the order of interest, and $r$ (# of successes) is the parameter defining the dominating term through
$P(r/n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} C_i^n q^{n-i}p^{i} \delta_{ir} = C_r^n q^{n-r}p^{r}$
where $P(r/n)$ is the probability to observe the event $r/n$ of $r$ successes out of $n$ trials. What is the Probability Theory narrative behind that? Why in order to obtain the PDF of a random binary process I should cherry-pick a term from a Taylor expansion of a binomial form? Seems so bizarre...
Forgive me my language, I am not a mathematician.
